# Is there any difference between "putting on" and "faking" (an accent)?

Tags: differences, connotation, nuance

I know they both mean "pretending to have" (a particular accent). Yet, I'm unsure if they can be used interchangeably. Are they both disapproving?

For example,

> - He was just faking a Scottish accent. He couldn't speak it at all!
> - He was just putting on a Scottish accent. He couldn't speak it at all!

Comment: **put on** [definition 3:](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/put+on#:~:text=To%20take%20on%20or%20give,Idiom%3A%20make%20believe.) *To assume affectedly: **put on an English accent.***

Comment: ... and 'fake' is certainly very often pejorative. Without further context, the 'just' would seem pejorative also. But 'Russ Abbott's execrable fake Scottish accent' might be seen as a tribute rather than a put-down. Context is vital (and as usual leads to complex analyses).

Comment: No, there can't be any difference. You're talking about things that **don't** match some specific definition, after all. There are an infinite number of ways that can happen, and there are not an infinite number of terms to describe them. The difference here is whether one wants a phrasal verb or a verbed noun.

Comment: @JohnLawler, Is "to put on an accent" as pejorative as "to fake an accent"?

Comment: That's a judgement that varies in speech groups, but to me it is. Both imply failure.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest a slight difference in meaning and then illustrate it with a personal account. I start with a choice (from many) of two meanings:

> To put on = to appear to have a feeling or way of behaving that is not real or not natural for you
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/put-on-something-someone)

> To fake = : Counterfeit,Simulate, Concoct
>
> “faked a heart attack”
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fake)

Considering these definitions, *to fake* is to simulate, whereas *to put on* may be to adopt something that is not simulated, may even be real, but is not natural to you.

My example is that I am English but have lived long enough in Scotland to be able to *put on* a West Scottish accent and word choice sufficiently good to occasionally persuade a Glasgow taxi driver that I am local. When I do this, my language is not *faked*, because I have learned it well; but it is *put on*, because it is not natural to me.

Comment: But as you say, this is a particularisation, cherry-picking an apparently arbitrary set of two polysemes. The terms are defined synonymously, and unravelling areas of non-overlap comprehensively would be a large task.

Comment: I think the real difference is that "fake" has more connotations of fraud or deception for some illicit purpose, while "put on" means it's not real or natural but not necessarily done to defraud or trick. So you would fake an accent if you're pretending to be from somewhere else, but you might put on an accent if you were an actor or doing impersonations or making fun of someone else's voice. This is implied by the quoted definitions and other dictionaries.

Comment: @StuartF, So when, for example, an American talk-show host does an impression of a British actor, he puts on rather than fake a British accent, right?

Comment: @BeatsMe If the host spent enough time studying & absorbing British accents that he has the ability to do it, then he is putting it on (he can do it but it is not natural for him to do so). If on the other hand he has little ability and merely imitates, he is faking. We used to see the same in Britain. English performers adopted fake Scottish accent for English audiences (lacing their speech with such as *wee*, *dram*, *lang*, *syne* etc)  that was clearly fake to any Scot. But some had assimilated so much Scots that they could put it on whenever they wished, appearing genuinely Scots to all.